# Is there a way to change cutoffs in the multimir-package without importing the files into R again?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am importing the same targetsets from the multimir-Package with different cutoffs.

Right now, I am using a loop to import the same targetsets multiple times but with different cutoffs:

```
miDB <- "pita"
cutoff <- c( 20,80,95,98,99)
for (DB in miDB) {
 for (miCutOff in cutoff) {
   miRNA_target_db = get_multimir(mirna=grouped_ID2, org="mmu", table=miDB, predicted.cutoff=miCutOff, summary=FALSE)
    }
}
```

That´s a mock-up of the code I am using. The problem is, that importing the data takes between 2-5 minutes depending on the targetset and the cutoff. Is there a way to import the data once with a cutoff of 99 (for example) and then change the cutoff to 98,95,80 and so on?